# iOS background image for all device screens from launch image

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

How can I use the iOS launch image dynamically as the background image for the current device screen being used within code?  Id hate to do a bunch of if/else statements to do this.  This is to small for an iPad.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
```

Comment: Why does anyone choose close without stating a reason?

Comment: What do you mean by "use the launch image dynamically"? Are you asking how to use an image as a background? Do you somehow have multiple launch images?

Comment: Yes, an iPhone application contains a dozen launch images used at startup depending on the device being used??????  I want to know this image and use it as the background on my device, unless this isnt a best practice. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html

Comment: As far as I know, iOS is only smart enough to differentiate between using the standard version of an image or the @2x version. If you support more than 2 images, such as for multiple screen sizes, you have no option but to go with the if/else statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out by using an asset catalog and using the launch image inside the new asset catalog with the name background.

```
UIColor *image = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background"]];
self.view.backgroundColor = image;
```